# Passing values from and to Popup forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making windows application.

I have requirement that ,  I need to open a pop up form from a Button click event , I can open that form through below code

```
Form2 frm = new  Form2();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

This Popup form `Form2` is data entry form , this will called from  `Form1`. `Form2` is data entry form. When I fill fields in `Form2` and click on Save button then all the values will be filled in `Form1's` grid.

And this grid also having Edit and Delete button.

How can I do that ? I have to save data in xml file and retrive from that but I dont want to do that.

Can anyone suggest any another way with sample code?

Answer (score 2):

You can have some `public properties` in your `form` to get and set data.

```
Form2 frm = new  Form2();
frm.FirstName = "John";
frm.ShowDialog();

string newFirstName = frm.FirstName;
```

Comment: should I retrive dataset instead of string ?

Comment: Yes, you have anything including Datasets.

Comment: I did this when i was a Developer on vb6 (long time ago) and now I remember this. It works nice...

Answer (score 0):

n this way, You can reach Form1 from Form2.

```
public class Form2
{
    private Form1 _instance;
    public Form2(Form1 instance)
    { 
          _instance = instance;   
    } 

    public void Save()
    {
         _intance.FillMethod();
    }
}

// this = form1 instance
Form2 frm = new  Form2(this);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

If some data is *required* by your data entry form, then it's better to pass data via constructor. Other data could be passed via properties, or even methods. Usage of properties is the best way to return data.

```
using(Form2 fom2 = new Form2(requiredData))
{
    form2.OtherData = optionalData;
    if (form2.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return;
    // read data from dialog form
    grid.DataSource = form2.Data;
    textBox.Text = form2.SomeString;
}
```